# Change the dropdown value as per page change

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="location-search"  onChange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"> > 
    <option value="http://dignitytech.com/efront/contact-us/">Ireland</option>

    <option value="http://dignitytech.com/efront/united-kingdom-2/">United Kingdom</option>

    <option value="http://dignitytech.com/efront/spain/">Spain</option>

    <option value="http://dignitytech.com/efront/romania/">Romania</option> 

</select>
```

Now i want to change the dropdown value as per page change.

Anybody help me

Comment: could you explain what you mean?

Comment: Something like: `$("#location-search").val( location.href );`

Comment: visit http://dignitytech.com/efront

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with this simple line of code executed on page load:

```
$('#location-search').val(location.href);
```

Comment: visit dignitytech.com/efront

Comment: Okay, what is the problem, I can see dropdown is properly preselected.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you already have, I'm assuming that you have exactly that select on multiple pages. If so, then simply on each page mark appropriate value (so when you're on `contact-us`, mark that option with `selected` attribute).